# Permanent damage from anti-inflammatory

Tags: toxicity, irreversible-damage, anti-inflammatory, internal-organs

The toxicity of anti-inflammatory drugs appears to be a well-estabilished issue, as outlined by papers such the one in https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2997980/.

What organs may be negatively affected by anti-inflammatory drugs? Is such damage permanent? Can it be gauged somehow?

Answer (score 1):

NSAIDs can also cause stomach ulcers, which may be fatal if left untreated. You can actually bleed to death.
References:
for ulcers:

- [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10749095)
- [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/digestive-disorders/tc/peptic-ulcer-disease-cause)

for death:

- [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8166110)
- [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/heartburn-gerd/complications-of-peptic-ulcer)

Comment: Any reliable references to support that?

Comment: I lost between 3 to 4 units of blood because of an ulcer and passed out because of blood loss. Had my wife not been here, I most likely would have laid on the floor and died. The ulcer was most likely the result of years of taking Naproxen. It was not because of any other risk factors, i.e. h. Pylori, GERD, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is also not uncommon (around 1:1000 if I'm not mistaken) to have normal doses of ibuprofen result in liver failure. The mechanism is still unknown.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Here on health it is required that all answers are backed up with reliable references, since they are the only way for the community to assess the merit of an answer regardless of the reader's background. You can always [edit] your question to add references. For more information on site policies, please take our [tour] and visit the [help] and [meta]. Thanks!

Comment: @Lucky well in this case my source was my Histology teacher. Should I post it in the comments instead?

Comment: @FilipeRocha- If you have a histology teacher, and you got this information from them, ask them for a reference to look it up. We would like something a little more concrete than "My teacher said".

Comment: @JohnP well I just checked the ibuprofen side effects and it does say "Liver Failure" as one possible